# ng-model data is not set when we click controller action

Tags: angularjs

Html page is defined as

```
        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
            <label  class="control-label col-md-2">Person Type</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control m-b" name="account" ng-model="person.type">
                  <option value="0" label="please select...">please select...</option>
                  <option value="Self"> Self </option>
                  <option value="Employee"> Company Employee </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
              <label class="control-label col-md-2">Person Name</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input class="form-control m-b" type="text" placeholder="Enter name of Person" ng-model="name">
              </div>
            </div>
```

controller function is defined as below

```
       controller('ClientCtrl' , function($scope, $http){     
        $scope.UpdatePerson= function(name, type){
        $scope.name= name ;
        $scope.person.type = type;
       };  })
```

after update value "$scope.name" value is changed but "$scope.person.type" is giving an error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined
at ChildScope.$scope.UpdatePerson (controller.js:277)
at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:15500), <anonymous>:4:1156)
at callback (angular.js:27285)
at ChildScope.$eval (angular.js:18372)
at ChildScope.$apply (angular.js:18472)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:27290)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
```

Comment: clearly `$scope.person` is undefined, try `$scope.person = {}` at the top of your controller

Comment: thanks , its works

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a defined $scope.person

```
$scope.person = {};
$scope.UpdatePerson= function(name, type){
    $scope.name= name ;
    $scope.person.type = type;
};
```

I think it was the formatting that got me, thought it was just some vars being initialized.

Comment: That would overwrite object every time he saves, it's not an update

Comment: You are right, I didn't see it was inside a function. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `person` is not defined:
I think this is the solution:
use [`ng-init`](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-init.asp) in order to prevent overwriting like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-12" ng-init="person={}">
        <label  class="control-label col-md-2">Person Type</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <select class="form-control m-b" name="account" ng-model="person.type">
              <option value="0" label="please select...">please select...</option>
              <option value="Self"> Self </option>
              <option value="Employee"> Company Employee </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
          <label class="control-label col-md-2">Person Name</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control m-b" type="text" placeholder="Enter name of Person" ng-model="name">
          </div>
        </div>
```